# Verbing in Latin

Tags: classical-latin, verbs, derivation, noun

Do we have any cases where the Romans intentionally conjugated a noun or adjective into a verb? This is common in English and other modern languages, so I'm assuming it is a natural concept. However, it seems that the Romans didn't often think of their grammar, as there do not appear to be native words for verb, noun, etc.

Comment: It doesn't always work:  ***Vir viret,*** means "The man is green."

Comment: How can you *conjugate* a noun into a verb? I think you meant [conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are at least some cases in which this can be done, with different shades of meaning.

> **graecisso (-izo), āre,** v. n., = Γραικίζω, to imitate the Greeks, to adopt a Grecian manner or tone: atque adeo hoc argumentum graecissat; tamen Non atticissat; verum sicelissat, Plaut. Men. prol. 7; v. Ritschl ad h. l.: graecizat, Consent. 1063 P.
>
> **atticisso, āre, v. n.,** = ἀττικίζω, to imitate the Athenian manner of speaking: hoc argumentum graecissat, tamen non atticissat, verum sicilicissitat, Plaut. Men. prol. 12; App. Flor. n. 18, p. 362, 12.
>
> **sicilisso or sicelisso, āre,** v. n. Siculi, to imitate Sicilian manners: hoc argumentum graecissat: tamen Non atticissat, verum sicelissat, Plaut. Men. prol. 8; v. Ritschl ad h. l.

And then there are some in *-or*:

> **cornīcor, āri,** v. dep. cornix, to caw like a crow (very rare): quid grave secum inepte, Pers. 5, 12; cf. Prisc. p. 828 P.; Hier. Ep. 125, n. 16.
>
> **rhētorico, āvi, 1 (ante-class.), and rhētoricor, āri, v. dep. (post-class.) [rhetoricus],** to speak rhetorically or like an orator, Novat. ap. Non. 476, 6 (Com. Rel. p. 216 Rib.); act. form, Tert. Res. Carn. 5.

(Though I'll note that there's also **rhētorisso, āre,**.)

My understanding is that this tendency is more common in ancient Greek than in Latin, but that's just from something my first Greek teacher said ten thousand years ago, so it could be totally wrong.

In any case, it seems to be fairly rare; then again, it's fairly rare in English too—we might talk about somebody "Clinton-izing" something or "Coulter-izing" something (sorry, politics on the brain), but not very often.

**EDIT:** An explanation from a different angle from 1841's *Linguæ Grammaticæ Rudimenta*:

[image]
[image]

Comment: 10K years ago would be *really* ancient Greek! Pre PIE, even :-)

Comment: Yeah, she was a REALLY forward-thinking teacher.

Comment: "My understanding is that this tendency is more common in ancient Greek than in Latin, but that's just from something my first Greek teacher said (...)." --- I heard this too.

Answer (score 6):

We can see how *miles, -itis* was adapted in *milito, militare*, and I seem to recall that *corinthio, -are* was "to work in Corinthian brass", so the short answer would be "yes".

I think that, with a bit of imagination, you could conduct a simple search to find or verify other examples.

There are certainly expressions for verb, recorded in some of the best writers, distinguishing *verba agentia*, *verba neutra* and *verba patiendi*. A proper noun is simply *nomen propria*, and so on.

Comment: I would have guessed verb to be *verbam actionis*

Comment: @tox123 It can't be _verbam actionis_ because _verbum_ is neuter, and would never have a -am ending.

Answer (score 6):

A noun can be turned into a verb in Latin.
But since both nouns and verbs have endings — quite incompatible ones one might add — an adjective cannot work as a verb as such.
Instead, slight modifications are needed.

In other words, verbs can be derived from nouns.
In English nouns and verbs can look alike, and the derivation need not do anything to the word, other than reinterpreting it as a verb.

Consider these derivations with minimal changes to the word, for example:

> *laus*, thank > *laudare*, thank
>   *vulnus*, wound > *vulnerare*, wound
>   *liber*, free > *liberare*, free
>   *finis*, end > *finire*, end

Comment: I can't just decide to make any verb a noun, can I? No "Grumio, Grumere, Grumivi, Grumitus" for me?

Comment: @tox123, do you mean making any noun a verb? Typically these derivations are first conjugation and regular. I see no problem with *grumo, grumare, grumavi, grumatus*, although you may need to explain what you mean by it if you use it. You can apply this to any noun I guess, although some of the new verbs will be more natural than others.

Comment: I believe tox123 is referring to the famous Grumio from the Cambridge Latin Course... Presumably "to behave in a Grumio-like fashion"? :)

Comment: @jogloran, I didn't realize that. I'm not familiar with that course or Grumio.

Comment: @tox123, I misinterpreted your comment, not knowing Grumio before another comment corrected me. If it's third declension (*Grumio*, *Grumionis*), I'd be tempted to use the verb *Grumionizari*. I've seen this *-izari* suffix to mean acting like someone.

Comment: @tox123 All hail the glorious Grumio! In our Latin class, we have declared Grumio a god, and have this whole religion and communist manifesto for him. It's pretty great. See [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/comparison-of-adjective-to-noun)  for a passage from His holy scripture.

Answer (score 4):

These are just denominative verbs and are quite common. From Allen & Greenough 258 (q.v.): "Verbs were formed in Latin from almost every from of noun-stem and adjective-stem."

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

***purus*** adj 'pure' (more simply than other examples given) becomes ***puro*** (rare) ritually purify.
And ***vivus,*** lifegiving, becomes ***vivo,*** I live,    So therefore:

> *butyro melleque vivo puro*

can be (Gilgamesh) "I purify with life-giving butter and honey;" or ([Winnie ille Pooh](http://www.arretetonchar.fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/IMG/archives/Divertissement/Latine%20Legere/Winnie%20Ille%20Pu.pdf)) "I live off pure butter and honey."

Comment: L&S says *puro* might be a *hapax legomenon*: I think it's worth noting that *purifico* is a much more standard way of saying "purify"

Comment: @brianpck Yet, there are a few noun /verb switches similar to English "I face book;" "You stackexchange;" "He googles."  ***dominus*** (or indeed domina) ***dominat*** is another.